# If I set multiple column as primary key for a table, does it still automatically create unique index for them?

Tags: sql, primary-key

I've been searching this for a while but just cannot find an answer. 
As far as I know, if there's a single primary key for a table. A unique index will be created automatically for this column.

But what about the case in which primary key are created for multiple column? I assume the same should happen for this . But correct me if I am wrong.

Thnx.

Comment: You can only have one primary key, but you can have multiple columns in your primary key.

Comment: There's a single `PRIMARY KEY`
 but additional *candidate keys* can be implemented using `UNIQUE`  constraints

Comment: @AnuragLal Hey, I probably described it poorly. I mean to set a primary key with multiple column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really have multiple separate *primary* keys, as there is always only a single primary key, at least in the flavors of SQL which I have seen/worked with.  What you can have is a primary key consisting of multiple *columns*.  In this case, the unique index would be on the composite of the two keys.  Actually, if you had a primary key on `(col1, col2)`, the DBMS might be able to use it even if only the `col1` column alone were involved, but the index itself would still be on two columns.

Comment: Thnx, excuse my poor description. What I wanted to ask is the case of a primary key bound with multiple columns.